# Creating reverse DNS entries which resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, reverse-dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse DNS - how to correctly configure for SMTP delivery](https://serverfault.com/questions/24943/reverse-dns-how-to-correctly-configure-for-smtp-delivery)

I ran a DNS check and ended up with the following error:

```
FAIL: Found reverse DNS entries which don't resolves
IP-IP-IP-IP.HOST.DOMAIN.TLD → ???
All IP's reverse DNS entries should resolve back to IP address (MX record's name -> IP -> IP Reverse -> IP). Many mail servers are configured to reject e-mails from IPs with inconsistent reverse DNS configuration.
```

How do I properly configure and it so it goes to an IP?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/24943/reverse-dns-how-to-correctly-configure-for-smtp-delivery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the provider who assigned the IP address to you. Unless they have delegated reverse DNS to you, then they will have to set it for you.

Answer (score -2):

[CloudFlare's New UI: Managing DNS records - CloudFlare blog](http://blog.cloudflare.com/118431940). You can get an idea from following guide: [Configuring Reverse DNS for BIND](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_25/WHMDocs/RdnsForBind),

*** UPDATE *** added CloudFlare link.

Comment: Can this be done via CloudFlare?

Comment: Please add a bit more content to your answer beyond just a link.  It might not be necessary to describe everything you read, but your answer should still be useful if that link 404s.